# Sidekiq and Redis on heroku; how best to ensure that every call is taken and no errors on Redis connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, heroku, redis, sidekiq

This is a fairly broad question but it's not clear to me which part is failing or how to make my code more likely to run succesfully.

I have a Rails app on Heroku and have gotten errrors like the following:

> there was an exception with Connection timed out
>
> Backtrace:
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:269:in
>   `write'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:269:in`
>   write'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:244:in
>   `block in write'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:226:in`
>   io'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:243:in
>   `write'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:204:in`
>   block (3 levels) in process'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:198:in
>   `each'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:198:in`
>   block (2 levels) in process'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:329:in
>   `ensure_connected'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:197:in`
>   block in process'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:279:in
>   `logging'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:196:in`
>   process'
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:102:in
>   `call' /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.

Presumably, this is because there is some connectivity issue with redistogo. Having these run is critical because we regenerate these JSON fragments and external javascript files and right now if redistogo is down (or whatever is happening in the above exception), nothing is raised. Specifically, I only get an email after 15 minutes. This is my first time using Sidekiq and really need to be alerted immediately. How best could I achieve that?

Here's the worker class that is being called:

```
class CatalogWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options({
                      backtrace: true,

                      # Should be set to true (enables uniqueness for async jobs)
                      # or :all (enables uniqueness for both async and scheduled jobs)
                      unique: :true,

                      # Unique expiration (optional, default is 30 minutes)
                      # For scheduled jobs calculates automatically based on schedule time and expiration period
                      expiration: 24 * 60 * 60
                  })


  def perform catalog_id, current_user_id, app_event_id
    CatalogGenerator.build cat_id, current_user_id: current_user_id, job_id: jid, app_event_id: app_event_id  #, note: note, current_user_id: current_user_id
  end
end
```

and my Catalog Generator

```
class CatalogGenerator

  def self.build id, note: "no note in calling", current_user_id: nil, job_id: "testme", app_event_id: nil, create_new_skq_current: true

    if app_event_id
      app_event=AppEvent.find(app_event_id)
      app_event_changes=app_event.attributes_changes
    else
      app_event_changes="UNKNOWN"
    end

    if current_user_id
      user=User.find(current_user_id)
      user_email=user.email
    else
      user_email="not sure"
    end
    mg_start=CatalogGenerationStart.index id, job_id, user_email
    mg_start.deliver

    # here's the part that matters
    begin
       CatalogGenerator.json_full(id)
    rescue => ex
      ecm=ExceptionCaughtMail.index ex, "CatalogGenerator.json_full with #{id}"
      ecm.deliver
    end

    begin
      CatalogGenerator.js_external(id)
    rescue => ex
      ecm=ExceptionCaughtMail.index ex, "CatalogGenerator.js_external with #{id}"
      ecm.deliver
    end

    begin
      CatalogGenerator.json(id)
    rescue => ex
      ecm=ExceptionCaughtMail.index ex, "CatalogGenerator.json with #{id}"
      ecm.deliver
    end

    begin
      CatalogImageGenerator.json(id)
    rescue => ex
      ecm=ExceptionCaughtMail.index ex, "CatalogImageGenerator.json with #{id}"
      ecm.deliver
    end
  end
```